# Getting the serialization properties from Saxon transformation

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

I have following XSL stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
   <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <test/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am using Saxon 9.9 to transform it like this.

```
public String transform(InputStream input, InputStream stylesheet, OutputStream output){
  Processor p = new Processor(false);
  XsltCompiler c = p.newXsltCompiler();
  XsltExecutable e = c.compile(new StreamSource(stylesheet));
  Xslt30Transformer xf = e.load30();
  Serializer s = p.newSerializer(output);
  xf.transform(new StreamSource(input), s);
  return s.getOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.ENCODING));
}
```

I would expect the return value to be "UTF-8" as specified in the stylesheet, but it returns null instead. (The serializer instance seems to have no properties at all.) Why is this, and what is the correct way to get the output properties?

Comment: Try `Serializer s = xf.newSerializer(output);` instead of `Serializer s = p.newSerializer(output);`.

Comment: http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Serializer.html#getCombinedOutputProperties-java.util.Properties- also suggests you might need `s.getCombinedOutputProperties().getProperty("encoding")`.

Comment: Creating the serializer through the `Xslt30Transformer` instance is indeed the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The interface between the XSLT transformation engine and the serializer is unfortunately very messy. It's messy in the XSLT spec, it's messy in JAXP, and it's messy in Saxon. I've made a number of attempts over the years to improve it, but it's still messy. There were some changes in Saxon 9.9, made necessary by the new and innocent-seeming (and in XSLT, almost useless) `item-separator` attribute, which has the effect that composing individual items into a document tree (if it happens at all) has to happen on the serialization side of the boundary, not on the transformation side.

The situation in the Saxon 9.9 s9api interface is that (in general) the Serializer object knows nothing about the serialization properties defined in the stylesheet, it only knows about those supplied directly via the Serializer API. Only when the Transformer invokes the Serializer to perform serialization do the two sets of serialization properties get combined.

The exception is when you use `Xslt30Transformer.newSerializer()` to create the serializer. In that case the serializer is initialized with the properties defined in unnamed `xsl:output` declarations in the stylesheet, as if they were set explicitly using `serializer.setOutputProperty()`.

The serialization properties defined in the stylesheet are available (though not very directly) as properties of the s9api `XsltExecutable`. This has a method `getUnderlyingCompiledStylesheet()` which returns a `PreparedStylesheet` object, and this has a method `getDeclaredSerializationProperties()` which returns properties defined on the default (unnamed) `xsl:output` declarations. There is also a method `getOutputProperties(name)` which returns properties for a named output format (as used in `xsl:result-document`)