# Getting serialization properties from an XQueryEvaluator in Saxon

Tags: xquery, saxon

I have asked this question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53801890/getting-the-serialization-properties-from-saxon-transformation), but now I am trying to get the serialization properties of an XQuery evaluation instead of an XSLT transformation.

Using this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SaxonApiException {
    Processor p = new Processor(false);
    XQueryEvaluator e = p.newXQueryCompiler().compile(
            "xquery version \"3.0\";" +
            "declare namespace output = \"http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization\"; " +
            "declare option output:encoding \"utf-8\";" +
            "<x s='ó'/>").load();
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Serializer s = p.newSerializer(os);
    e.setDestination(s);
    e.run();
    assert "utf-8".equals(s.getCombinedOutputProperties(null).getProperty("encoding")); //fails
}
```

The ways proposed in the answers to the original question seem not to be applicable here, because it I cannot instantiate a serializer from an `XQueryEvaluator`, and `getDeclaredSerializationProperties` is only available in an XSLT context.

I'm using Saxon 10 HE.

Comment: Which version of Saxon do you use or which version(s) do you target?

Comment: I'm using Saxon 10 HE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an `XQueryExecutable` e:

```
e.getUnderlyingCompiledQuery().getExecutable().getPrimarySerializationProperties()
```

I can't immediately see a way to do it from the `XQueryEvaluator`, but since the `XQueryEvaluator` is always created from an `XQueryExecutable` by calling `load()`, you should be able to start from there.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible if you subclass `Serializer` and override the method `getReceiver` to access/store the SerializationParameters passed in to that method:

```
public class MySerializer extends Serializer {

    public MySerializer(Processor processor) {
        super(processor);
    }
    
    
    private SerializationProperties mySerProps;
    
    public SerializationProperties getSerProps() {
        return mySerProps;
    }
    @Override
    public Receiver getReceiver(PipelineConfiguration arg0, SerializationProperties arg1) throws SaxonApiException {
        mySerProps = arg1;
        return super.getReceiver(arg0, arg1);
    }

}
```

Then use e.g.

```
        MySerializer s = new MySerializer(p);
        s.setOutputStream(os);
        e.setDestination(s);
        e.run();
        assert "utf-8".equals(s.getSerProps().getProperty("encoding"));
```